# LaTeX Flow Chart Path Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, paths

I have a flow chart that has all of the nodes that I want, there is just one path that I can't get.

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {Set Quotient to 0};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {Subtract Divisor from Dividend};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {Add 1 to Quotient};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {is Result Register Greater than 0?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {Stop - Quotient is Correct};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {no}(stop);
    \end{tikzpicture}

% use \figcap to build the caption. DO NOT use the default \caption command
\figcap{Control scheme for Repeated Subtraction Division} % put the caption of your figure here
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to add a path that loops from the last block (stop) to the block (identify). Whenever I try to do this I get a path that does not go around the blocks, but rather through them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use relative coordinates (`++(2cm,0)`) then vertical-horizontal paths (`|-`) :

```
\path[line] (stop) -- ++(2cm,0) |- (identify);
```

The completed code using `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` (cf. [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372))

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\tikzset{%
  decision/.style={
    diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered,
    node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt,
  },
  block/.style={
    rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered,
    rounded corners, minimum height=4em,
  },
  line/.style={
    draw, -latex',
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
  % Place nodes
  \node [block] (init) {Set Quotient to 0};
  \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {Subtract Divisor from Dividend};
  \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {Add 1 to Quotient};
  \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {is Result Register Greater than 0?};
  \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {Stop - Quotient is Correct};
  % Draw edges
  \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
  \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
  \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
  \path [line] (decide) -- node {no}(stop);
  % Loop
  \path[line] (stop) -- ++(-2cm,0) |- (identify);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a second alternative via matrix notes from TikZ. In this way the vertical distance is set by the `rowsep` or (`colsep` for 2D orientations) without using `node distance` commands and the use `below= of ...` is minimal as well. (The same idea applies to 2D orientations, especially for flow chart diagram, IHMO)

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, fill=red!20, minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
% Place nodes with matrix nodes
 \matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]{%
    \node [block] (init) {Set Quotient to 0};\\
    \node [block] (identify) {Subtract Divisor from Dividend};\\
    \node [block] (evaluate) {Add 1 to Quotient};\\
    \node [decision] (decide) {is Result Register Greater than 0?};\\
    \node [block] (stop) {Stop - Quotient is Correct};\\};
% Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);  
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node[right]{No} (stop);
    \path [line] (stop) -- ++(2,0) |- (identify);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that it is better to exploit `tikzset` rather than `tikzstyle`; see: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304).